# Extend interface of third party library, and then reuse that definition

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I have a Material-UI theme that I'm adding some custom types to. They custom types look something like this:

```
import * as createPalette from '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette';
export declare module '@material-ui/core/styles/createPalette' {
  interface PaletteOptions {
    success?: PaletteColorOptions;
    warning?: PaletteColorOptions;
    blue?: PaletteColorOptions;
  }
  interface Palette {
    blue: ColorPartial;
  }
  interface Theme {
    palette: Palette;
  }
  interface ThemeOptions {
    palette: Palette;
  }
}
```

This works, and I can finally add my custom blues to my `Palette`. The trouble is that the project in which I'm developing this theme is then reused in other projects.

When I again use the extended type in another project (where I have imported this one as a module), I get a TS error.

```
Property 'blue' does not exist on type 'Palette'.  TS2339

    33 |     },
    34 |     selected: {
  > 35 |       backgroundColor: theme.palette.blue[100],
       |                                      ^
    36 |     },
    37 |     counts: {
    38 |       color: theme.palette.grey['600'],
```

I can fix this error by copying the overrides file from one project to the other, but I'd like to avoid doing that, as I'm likely to modify the overrides, and I don't want to add an extra step for folks that are using the theme within my organization.

Is there some way to properly export these overrides so that they will just work when the module is installed?

Comment: Could you make a new interface instead of declaration merging with the original, then cast to the new interface and export from your module?

Comment: Is your interface in a `.d.ts` ?

Comment: My interface is defined in a `.d.ts` file, yes. @Zze

Comment: @101arrowz I think that may work. I'll give it a shot. The interesting thing is that this actually worked in an earlier version of typescript. I think 2.7.x, and now i'm on version 2.9. The nice thing was, that I seemed to be able to use it very transparently, without having to export my own module. It just seemed to extend the one I imported from the third party, which was perfect.